# How to noclip in The Stanley Parable (2013)

Tags: the-stanley-parable

I really appreciate the little jokes and funny things the developer put into this game, but how do I really enable cheats to get into noclip mode?

I tried running the game with +sv_cheats 1 in command line, and binding "sv_cheats 1" to a key in the config.cfg file and then making the config file read-only. This worked with the unachievable achievement according to an answer to another question here.

None of these things seem to work? Is there some kind of developer hack to get into noclip mode?

Comment: It is a source game, so enabling the console with -console in the launch options and then using the command noclip should work.

Comment: @John That's what I thought, but apparently that just makes it load up without the console and the Narrator telling you that cheating is no fun.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie console is enabled, but executing 'sv_cheats 1' just teleports you to a room.

Answer (score 4):

I read on a steam thread ([How to Cheat](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221910/discussions/0/792924412062632220/#c792924412065915012)) that the developer will authorize cheats when all secrets have been found.

Comment: The fact that they haven't been authorized yet fills me with excitement.

Comment: Might be his way of saying: I won't authorize cheats